# Using '+' as an actual + operator when passed as string - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am setting a state property as such: `state = { sign: '' }`
and set it to either `'+'` or `'-'`.

The plan is to then use this within a calculation. For example, imagine `sign` is set to `'+'`, I will use the operator in a calculation such as: `12 sign 8`. However, when I am outputting the result, I am getting `12+8` rather than `20`.

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Comment: num1 + (+this.state.sign )+ num2

Comment: hey yo. u can make smth like if(sign=='+') some + some...

Comment: `const operator = sign === '-' ? -1 : 1; 12 + (operator) * 8`.

Comment: Also note that in mathematics sign '+' '-' has different meaning than the binary operators '+' and '-', so you better call your property operator. That is state= {operator: ''}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using conditionals
2. Using switch

```js
var sign = '+';
console.log("Using conditionals");
console.log(sign==='+' ? 12+8 : 12-8);

//Switch
console.log("Using switch");
switch(sign)
{
    case '+' : console.log(12+8);break;
    case '-' : console.log(12-8);break;
    default : console.log("not valid operation");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of eval function

```
eval(a + this.state.sign + b)
```

The argument of the `eval()` function is a string. If the string represents an expression, `eval()` evaluates the expression

Answer (score 0):

there is eval() in javascript to evaluate a string.

```
var operation=12+ sign+ 8
console.log(eval(operation))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use eval in javascript

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```js
 state = { sign: '+' }

console.log(eval(2 + this.state.sign + 6))
```